# Automatic type deduction in template function using namespaces and friend declaration doesn't work in Clang

Tags: templates, gcc, c++11, clang++, friend-function

I have some trouble compiling a piece of C++ code using Clang 3.3 on linux. However the same piece of code compiles with gcc 4.8.2 as well as Intel Compiler. So I wanted if my code is actually legal. Usually I trust clang more with such questions ;)

Anyway, so here is the code fragment:

```
namespace test {
   template<class SCALAR=double>
    struct Foo {
     public:
      template<class SCALAR_ARG>
      friend Foo<SCALAR_ARG> create_Foo( );

      typedef SCALAR scalar_t;
    };

    template<class SCALAR_ARG=double>
    Foo<SCALAR_ARG> create_Foo( )
    {
      typedef Foo<SCALAR_ARG> impl_t;
      return impl_t();
    }

}

struct Dummy {
  typedef Dummy impl_t;
};

int main() {
  typedef test::Foo<Dummy> foo_t;
  typedef typename foo_t::scalar_t scalar_t;

  Dummy  egv_;
  test::create_Foo();

  return 0;
}
```

What do you think? Should I post it as bug in Clang or is it actually ill-formed?

Thanks in Advance,
Raffael

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be good to see what error you actually get with clang.
2. You have a lot of noise in the code you posted, parts that
   are unrelated to the problem.
3. Here is how you should deal with [template friends](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html).

Following the advice given there, here is how I fixed your code:

```
namespace test {

  template <class > struct Foo;

  template <class T=double> Foo<T> create_Foo();

  template<class SCALAR=double>
    struct Foo {
    public:

      friend Foo create_Foo<>( );

      typedef SCALAR scalar_t;
    };

    template<class SCALAR_ARG>
    Foo<SCALAR_ARG> create_Foo( )
    {
      typedef Foo<SCALAR_ARG> impl_t;
      return impl_t();
    }

}

struct Dummy {
  typedef Dummy impl_t;
};

int main() {
  typedef test::Foo<Dummy> foo_t;
  typedef typename foo_t::scalar_t scalar_t;

  Dummy  egv_;
  test::create_Foo();

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles both with gcc 4.7.2 and clang++ 3.4 (trunk).